# Each user can create a group with curtain functionalities and others users can join ? Database Design

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-design

The application I have to design is the following:

- A group has several functionalities that each user can access and
  work with. It is not a chatting group. It it like having data that
  each user can add/edit based on his privileges.
- Each user can create or join as many groups as he/she likes.

My question is what is the best way to design a database for such task.
*Examples similar to what I want to achieve exist on live sites such as:
Deviantart's groups, Trello, Facebook's groups, LinkedIn company pages etc*

I have two ways that sound good but I may miss something important:

1. I was thinking that one database is the best way, and create
   associations with the groups and the users. This way though makes me
   think about performance. What will happen if/when there will be
   thousands or even million of users and maybe more groups available.
   Will a mysql database handle all the requests and respond quickly ?
2. An other suggestion was made to me that I could split each group
   into different tables. So when a user connects the requests that
   will happen will be only based on the groups he/she has joined. Only to
   those tables. With that approach I see a database full of tables
   that will not be able to manage later on, as more groups get
   created.

Am I overthinking that I will have performance issues ?
Is there a technology that I am missing that could help with my situation ?

This application will be developed in laravel 5 with mysql database and angular 2.

Thank you in advance!

John,

Have a nice and creative day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user signs up, they can create a group and follow other groups and add items to groups.

**User table design example:**

```
id|email|username|password
```

**Groups table design example:**

```
id|user_id|title|description
```

user_id = person that created group.

**Items table design example:**

```
id|user_id|title|content
```

user_id = person that added item.

**GroupUsers table design example:**

```
id|group_id|user_id|role
```

role = admin or moderator or follower or whatever you want that user to be able to do for that group. You can have the same user_id assigned to many group_id.

**GroupItems table design example:**

```
id|group_id|item_id
```

I wrote this out quickly and may not be perfect by any means, this should give you an idea of one technique. If you do not understand relational databases. Please go learn.

Comment: hey Chris, correct me if I am wrong. The only reason this way would result in performance issues is due to low quality server(s) right ?

Comment: @JohnBoulmetis Yes you could scale this with a dedicated database server and add clusters onto that as you grow. Speak with your hosting tech for more details or recommendations.